# Integral with residue

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I wanted to ask you how to convert and calculate the integral with Residues.

$${\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-3x^2)-\pi x(1-x^2)\cot(\pi x)}{2x^2(1-x^2)}\,dx}$$